# could not connect to server: Operation timed out

Tags: postgresql

I am able to ssh into my ubuntu server with a user name and password from the terminal. However, when I try to connect to the server using the same name and password via pgadmin, I am getting the following error:

could not connect to server: Operation timed out Is the server running on host "xx.xxx.xx.xxx" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Why am I able to connect through terminal but not pgadmin?

Comment: Please show the command line used to connect to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Because your firewall is blocking port 5432, maybe?  If port 22 is open, and port 5432 is not, that would be why.